# Creating an absolute path

Tags: java

The Java `Paths` class has this useful method for creating a `Path` object:

```
Path path = Paths.get("a", "b", "c", "d", "e.txt");
```

However, with this approach the resultant path is relative to the invoking directory.  What is the best **platform-independent** way to get an absolute path (one which transparently incorporates both the Windows `\` and the Unix `/` conventions)?

Comment: I don't think that even makes sense, as you also have different file system roots ("/" on Linux, "C:" or similar on Windows). Anyway, `Paths.get("/usr", "bin", "bash")` should work according to the Javadoc. And if you already have a relative path which you want to convert to an absolute one, `myPath.toAbsolutePath()` is your friend.

Comment: What are the parameters for the absolute path?  Windows accepts the Unix forward-slash convention.  File.separator gives you a platform-specific path separator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `Path` object that needs to be an absolute path instead, you can just invoke `toAbsolutePath()` on it; note that path objects know what the platform separator is; it is already platform independent, there's no need to manually convert any slashes.

If you mean: I have a bunch of strings and I want on unix to obtain a path representing `/a/b/c/d/e.txt` but on windows to obtain a path representing `C:\a\b\c\d\e.txt` that's a problem. Because `C:` is not actually something you just get to assume.

Your question is then unanswerable: Turns out that if you want to be fully platform independent, there is no such notion as 'the root directory'. On windows, one can only speak of 'a root directory', and there are as many as file systems hooked up to a drive letter, and that too is a tricky abstraction, because really windows works with a `\\drive-identifier\path` model.

Something you may want to investigate:

```
for (Path p : FileSystems.getDefault().getRootDirectories()) {
    System.out.println("Found a root: " + p);
}
```

You could for example go with 'just go off of the first root, whatever it is':

```
Path root = FileSystems.getDefault().getRootDirectories().iterator().next();
Path p = root.resolve(Paths.get("a", "b", "c", "d", "e.txt"));
System.out.println(p);
```

Whether that is the root you intended (presumably, C:) - that'll depend on quite a few factors.

The best thing to do is to forget about having separate strings. If you are taking user input representing an absolute path, take one, single string. A user on windows is bound to type something like: `C:\Users\Sandeep\hello.txt`, and `Paths.get()` has no problem with that input at all. A user on mac might type `/Users/Sandeep/hello.txt` and this too works just fine if you feed it to `Path`, and operations from there on out are entirely platform independent already.